# CSS styling for table

Tags: html, css, html-table

i am trying to populate values to HTML table. I am able to populate values to table but struggling to style the table.

Following is the table style i would like to have. Please help me to style my table as the image looks below.

Thanks a lot for the comments you provided, yes with >800 rep i have learned a lot from SO only.

Please have a look at the table i tried.

```
<!-- CSS goes in the document HEAD or added to your external stylesheet -->
<style type="text/css">
table.hovertable {
    font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#333333;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #999999;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.hovertable th {
    background-color:#c3dde0;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #a9c6c9;
}
table.hovertable tr {
    background-color:#d4e3e5;
}
table.hovertable td {
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #a9c6c9;
}
</style>
<!-- Table goes in the document BODY -->
<table class="hovertable">
<tr>
    <th>Info Header 1</th><th>Info Header 2</th><th>Info Header 3</th>
</tr>
<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">
    <td>Item 1A</td><td>Item 1B</td><td>Item 1C</td>
</tr>
<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">
    <td>Item 2A</td><td>Item 2B</td><td>Item 2C</td>
</tr>
<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">
    <td>Item 3A</td><td>Item 3B</td><td>Item 3C</td>
</tr>
<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">
    <td>Item 4A</td><td>Item 4B</td><td>Item 4C</td>
</tr>
<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">
    <td>Item 5A</td><td>Item 5B</td><td>Item 5C</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Thanks and Regards.
[image]

Comment: and your table html / css until now is?

Comment: Please help *us* to help *you*, show us your HTML. Tell us where you're stuck. We're not here to do your work for you, we're here to help; with your current rep > 800, you should *know* that already.

Comment: Please provide your html markup and how you try styling it.

Comment: Put box-shadow, or image, at the table top, nice border at the th bottom, make some text bold... solved! :)

Comment: The sample code does not match the content in the image. And you should specify the particular presentational feature(s) that you are having problems with, and how you tried to address them, instead of asking others to design a style sheet that implements the presentation shown in an image. For example, your code shows no attempt at rgiht-aligning some columns, which is an obvious request, judging from the image.

Answer (score 1):

This is the css which resolved my problem,

```
border: 1px  #CCC solid;
    box-shadow: 
        inset 0px 11px 8px -10px #CCC,
        inset 0px -11px 8px -10px #CCC;
```